# Python Logging - closing filehandlers for multiple modules

Tags: python, logging, filehandler

I'm trying to log info from multiple modules that I've created. I have a main script (`main.py`) and another module (let's call it `mymodule.py`). I've set up a logger in each module as follows:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create a file handler
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('debug.log', mode='a')
file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create a logging format
# we're limiting the levelname to 1 char: I=INFO, D=DEBUG and so on
formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(levelname).1s][%(module)14s:%(funcName)-15s]-> %(message)s')
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

# add the handler to the logger
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

In main.py I load `mymodule.py` and I do the following at the end of all processing.

```
file_handler.close()
logger.removeHandler(file_handler)
```

Now the problem is that once the script stops running I can't delete debug.log unless I close Spyder. Also, for each subsequent run I get duplicate entries from `mymodule.py` like this.

```
[D][mymodule:__init__       ]-> object created
[D][mymodule:__init__       ]-> object created
```

So it appears that there is an open file handler that I've left hanging. How do I close it. If I have to add a `file_handler.close()` in `mymodule.py` where do I add it?

EDIT: I tried this in `main.py`

```
# clean up file handlers
handlers = logger.handlers[:]
for handler in handlers:
    handler.close()
    logger.removeHandler(handler)
```

Comment: Have you checked `logger.handlers` to see that you have indeed removed all handlers at the end?

Comment: I tried updating main.py. Please see the edited question. That didn't help.

Comment: Use  `logging` like described here: https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/logging.html#logging-from-multiple-modules

Comment: I could use that method if I wasn't using a custom logger but I'd like to use a custom logger.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spyder, then your variables are probably alive for the entire lifetime of the workspace. You should just delete the variable `file_handler`:

```py
file_handler.close()
del file_handler
```